# Aframe selectstart event from VR mode happens when touch on any place scene is clicked; touchclick on concrete a-entity is expected

Tags: javascript, aframe, virtual-reality

have such issue:

using  this approach: 
on touchclick event, from xr mode. 
  currSphere.sceneEl.renderer.xr.getSession().addEventListener('selectstart', ev => { 
                       console.log('sphere is clicked; event target:', ev.target);
   });
via selectstart event
if user make clicktouch on screen, from vr(xr) mode
binded  to a-entity selectstart eventhandler is called, 
but when *clicked any possible place on whole scene*.

(any on this can be appearing some time; this looks weird to me)
Please look at demo on glitch:

http://chrome-80.glitch.me
code is available here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/4eb40938-196b-4cb2-8670-fd3cce3d0eb3
Browser chrome 79+; google vr services installed.

Expected behavior: only when click a-entity , not any place on whole scene we should got eventlistener handler calling.
2. for 2 different entities , as on demo
expecting different event hanler called on differnet entity.
e.q: touchclick on box: console.log('box is clicked');
 touchclick on sphere: console.log('sphere is clicked');

current behavior :
 when clicked any place on a-scene, by selectstart event,  hapenning only a-sphere eventlistener.
also possible: sometimes neither one of them is clicked.

Any ideas? i also available in aframe slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior. Screen touches via `select` event don't provide tap coordinates so it cannot be associated with an entity in the scene. The standard API is still under discussion and it will evolve to include more information. I recommend using a [fuse and gazed base cursor](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html#properties_fuse) in the meantime.

Comment: Hello, Diego! nice to see you here, as i have told erlier, unfort. we can not to use fulse cursor just if user hovering camera (curiosly) on invisible point he will reveal this point. by accident,. (goal of project is for user: to find points and reveal them intentionally, explitly). We thinking about laser cursor. how expensive they are for user?

Comment: thank you for checking http://chrome-80.glitch.me/, yes looks you are right, if click on any place of scene sphere or box still clicked.

Comment: good, done as you asked. this app working only with VRbox, google cardboard , etc. currenltly we see only bluetooth remote controller handy. what not expencive controllers except bt. gamepad you cann recommend. this not topic question. )

Comment: Good evening! i've just make example more simple and so close to original as i've could. Could you please re check it.
https://chrome-80.glitch.me/ why is that?
--- https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/4eb40938-196b-4cb2-8670-fd3cce3d0eb3
expected behavior: box should change color on click;
actually: in xr mode click is not working.
---
more info:
simple, looks clear and innocent mosedown event.
should work from chrome 80 xr mode, but unf. it is not. tested from galaxy s9 android;
chrome 80; google vr services installed